# vaadin external javascript file location

Tags: vaadin7

I've got several `javascript` files.
I want to import it on my page, created using vaadin.

I added annotation `@JavaScript` to my `UI`.

```
@JavaScript({ "prettify.js", "vkbeautify.js", "additional.js" })
```

I put it into `VAADIN\themes\theme-name`.

However when I try to run it

```
WARNING: prettify.js published by com.folder.ui.AdminUi not found. Verify that the file com/folder/ui/prettify.js is available on the classpath.
```

Where I should put it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

For maven based projects, the script files belong under the resource folder.
**Example: src/main/resources/com/folder/ui**

For Ivy/Eclipse based projects, the scripts go in the same path as your class src/main/java/com/folder/ui

The maven based projects generally mess people up because all Vaadin docs are written for Ivy.

Hope this helps,
Malcolm